# what is this docx header style lang value "und"?

Tags: docx, phpword

I work on a web application that allows users to upload files. Files with certain formats (e.g. PDF, DOC, XLS, etc.) are scraped using [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice) libraries like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord). Recently a user uploaded a DOCX file that lead to an error:

```
Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: und is not a valid language code in C:\Atlas\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Style\Language.php:252
```

I considered posting an issue on the PHPWord github repository but wanted to know more about what was causing the error.

I renamed the DOCX file as a zip and opened it up. Within the zip at path `word/styles.xml` I found the XML that contains `"und"`:

```xml
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Header">
    <w:name w:val="Header"/>
    <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:next w:val="Header"/>
    <w:autoRedefine w:val="0"/>
    <w:hidden w:val="0"/>
    <w:qFormat w:val="1"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="center" w:leader="none" w:pos="4153"/>
            <w:tab w:val="right" w:leader="none" w:pos="8306"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:suppressAutoHyphens w:val="1"/>
        <w:spacing w:after="200" w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto"/>
        <w:ind w:leftChars="-1" w:rightChars="0" w:firstLineChars="-1"/>
        <w:textDirection w:val="btLr"/>
        <w:textAlignment w:val="top"/>
        <w:outlineLvl w:val="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:w w:val="100"/>
        <w:position w:val="-1"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        <w:effect w:val="none"/>
        <w:vertAlign w:val="baseline"/>
        <w:cs w:val="0"/>
        <w:em w:val="none"/>
        <w:lang w:bidi="ar-SA" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:val="und"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

Notice towards the end is this element:

```
<w:lang w:bidi="ar-SA" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:val="und"/>
```

It appears that `w:style` element corresponds to the header and there is a similar element for the footer that also contains a child element `w:lang` with attribute `w:val="und"`.

Does that attribute correspond to the value being *undefined* or something else? Can it be changed within MS Word?

---

## Update Jan 20, 2023

I've [logged an issue on the GH repo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/2371)

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/how-rms-matches-lang-tags. **Undetermined language**
A resource may be tagged as "und" to indicate that it matches any language. This tag may also be used with a script tag to filter matches based on script. For example, "und-Latn" will match any language tag that uses Latin script. Also this link https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Comment: Okay thanks - I've [logged an issue on the GH repo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/2371)